# D-Bus API or C library to control firewalld

Tags: c, embedded-linux, dbus, gdbus, firewalld

I'm working on a project, implementing everything in C language. As a part of the project, we need to be able to control and configure `firewalld`, firewall of the current system.

- `firewalld` is implemented in Python and an interface is available. However, we don't want to make Python calls from C or vice versa.
- There are command line tools to configure `firewalld` (e.g. `firewall-cmd`) but we don't want to make such calls from C either.

I recently started working on `firewalld`, I don't know much about its internals. I've read that it uses D-Bus, I also don't know much about D-Bus.

- There is a C library developed by Thomas Woerner: [`libfirewall`](https://github.com/firewalld/libfirewall). 
  However, it's been more than a year and a half since the last commit so it's not maintained. Other than `libfirewall`, I don't know any firewalld interface in C.

  - I gave `libfirewall` a shot. It got me some problems when both compiling and running the examples and I still have problems to resolve. Is it worth to continue with `libfirewall`? Should I use it?
  - Is there any other interface that I'm not aware of?
- *Possibly naive question due to lack of understanding of D-Bus:* I thought, maybe, with a D-Bus interface, I can issue commands to firewalld. Can it be done? (i.e. Does D-Bus work like that?) Can we write a program that mimics, say `firewall-cmd`, and interacts with D-Bus in the same way and at the end allows us to control firewalld?

  - If this is possible, how to do it and what to use? [`libdbus`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/) and `GDBus` have relatively good documentation although `libdbus` requires good deal of effort. They even said *"If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain."* in the documentation. In any case I'll be in need of examples or any kind of text demonstrating their usage.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can issue commands to firewalld via D-Bus. I haven't checked but expect that `firewall-cmd` is itself implemented as a D-Bus client.

The D-Bus API is extensively documented: https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.dbus.html. The documentation should give you a rough idea what can be accomplished through the API. You could try the D-Bus debugger `d-feet` to interact with firewalld without any code.

GDBus is definitely the easiest way use D-Bus from C but it's still not trivial and firewalld is a fairly complex API: Using it may require some expertise (completely depending on what you need to do).